# I am receiving vba automation error -2147319767, how can I solve this?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file that since a windows/office update I keep getting runtime errors from. The code looks completely fine and the ranges/sheets all exist and have contents. Sometimes the error fixes itself, then another one pops up. I have added the debug line in bold.

I'm not sure why this keeps happening tbh.

```
Sub ImportRawLastWeek()

Dim ImportRawData As Workbook

    Set ImportRawData = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last Weeks Report").Range("A1").Value, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    ImportRawData.Activate
    
    With ImportRawData.Sheets("Total Disabled")
        **.Range("A8", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 41)).Copy**
    End With
    
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Last Weeks Report").Activate
    
    Sheets("Last Weeks Report").Cells(8, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ImportRawData.Close False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it by chance a `xls`-file? Add a dot before `Rows.Count`

Comment: It's a .xlsb file. Tried your suggestion but error remains the same.

Comment: Try breaking up the problem line into multiple steps: (1) find the last row (is it as expected?), (2) set a range variable to the range to be copied, (3) copy the range.  Which step errors?

Comment: Yes last row is correct . When I receive the runtime error, the highlighted selection area stops at Column R (19) instead of column 41 as stipulated by the offset. I dont know why as there is no gaps or extra information there. I have changed how to assigned the range and still the same

Comment: Ok so I broke it down and used code I found elsewhere and this is where I now get an error:   

 With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With